# Perl's odd behavior of index() when called with empty substr with vs without Encode::decode()

Tags: perl

I have created a very small sample code below to illustrate how Perl's `index()` function's return value changes for empty `substr` ("") on string that is passed or not passed through `Encode::decode()`.

```
use strict;
use Encode;

my $mainString = (@ARGV >= 2) ? $ARGV[1] : "abc";
my $subString  = (@ARGV >= 3) ? $ARGV[2] : "";
if (@ARGV >= 1) {
    $mainString = Encode::decode("utf8", $mainString);
}

my $position = index($mainString, $subString, 0);
my $loopCount = 0;
my $stopLoop  = 7; # It goes for ever so set a stopping value
while ($position >= 0) {
    if ($loopCount >= $stopLoop) {
        last;
    }
    $loopCount++;

    print "[$loopCount]: $position \"$mainString\" [".length($mainString)."] ($subString)\n";
    $position = index($mainString, $subString, $position + 1);
}
```

Before getting into with vs without `Encode::decode()`, what should the return value of `index()` be for an empty `substr` ("") because [Perl's documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index) does not mention it. Although it does not mention it, here is the execution result **without** calling `Encode::decode()` for ASCII characters "abc" (`@ARGV = 0`):

```
>perl StringIndex.pl
[1]: 0 "abc" [3] ()
[2]: 1 "abc" [3] ()
[3]: 2 "abc" [3] ()
[4]: 3 "abc" [3] ()
[5]: 3 "abc" [3] ()
[6]: 3 "abc" [3] ()
[7]: 3 "abc" [3] ()
```

However when encoding is involved, the return value changes. The return value changes as if the string being searched is not bounded by its length when called **with** `Encode::decode()` for ASCII characters "abc" (`$ARGV[0] = 1`):

```
>perl StringIndex.pl 1
[1]: 0 "abc" [3] ()
[2]: 1 "abc" [3] ()
[3]: 2 "abc" [3] ()
[4]: 3 "abc" [3] ()
[5]: 4 "abc" [3] ()
[6]: 5 "abc" [3] ()
[7]: 6 "abc" [3] ()
```

As a Side Note:

1. `substr` is set to empty string ("") in above example, but in my real program it is a variable that changes value depending on condition.
2. I understand the simplest solution is to check if `substr` is empty and not enter the `while` loop
3. I am using "This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built
   for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be considered a bug, which I've reported [here](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/18588).

---

Minimal code to reproduce:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings qw( void );
use feature qw( say );

my $s = "abc";
my $len = length($s);
utf8::upgrade($s);
length($s) if $ARGV[0];
say index($s, "", $len+1);
```

```
$ perl a.pl 0
3

$ perl a.pl 1
4
```

---

Perl has two string storage formats. The "upgraded" format, and the "downgraded" format.

`Encode::decode` always return an upgraded string. And `utf8::upgrade` tells Perl to switch the storage format used by a scalar.

Each character of a downgraded string can store a number between 0 and 255. Each character of the string is stored as a byte of the appropriate value. This, of course, is fine if you have bytes or ASCII text. But this is insufficient for arbitrary text.

Each character of an upgraded string can store a number between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup>-1 or between 0 and 2<sup>64</sup>-1 depending on how your Perl was compiled. This is more than enough to store any Unicode Code Point (even those outside the BMP). Each character is encoded using "utf8", a nonstandard extension of UTF-8.

utf8 (like UTF-8) is variable-length encoding. This presents two problems:

- Determining the length of an upgraded string requires iterating over the entire string.
- Determining the position of characters in a upgraded string requires iterating over the entire string.

Let's consider the following snippet:

```perl
index($str, $substr, $pos)
```

With a downgraded string, `index` can jump directly to the position indicated by `$pos`. It's a question of simple pointer arithmetic.

But because each character of an upgrade string can require a different amount of storage, `index` can't use pointer arithmetic to find the character at position `$pos`. Without optimizations, each use to `index` would have to start at offset 0 and move through the string until it finds the character indicated by `$pos`.

That would be unfortunate. Imagine if `index` was being used in a loop to find all matches. So Perl optimizes this! When the length of an upgraded string becomes known, Perl attaches it to the scalar.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'
   $s = "abc";
   utf8::upgrade($s);
   Dump($s);
   length($s);
   Dump($s);
'
SV = PV(0x56483dda7e80) at 0x56483ddd5ba0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x56483ddda3f0 "abc"\0 [UTF8 "abc"]
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 10
SV = PVMG(0x56483de0ecf0) at 0x56483ddd5ba0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (SMG,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0x56483ddda3f0 "abc"\0 [UTF8 "abc"]
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 10
  MAGIC = 0x56483ddd4050
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_utf8
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_utf8(w)
    MG_LEN = 3                           <-- Attached length
```

Similarly, the offset of characters is sometimes attached to the scalar as well!

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'
   $s = "abc";
   utf8::upgrade($s);
   Dump($s);
   index($s, "", 2);
   Dump($s);
'
SV = PV(0x558d5c970e80) at 0x558d5c99ebc0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x558d5c9ae3a0 "abc"\0 [UTF8 "abc"]
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 10
SV = PVMG(0x558d5c9d7d10) at 0x558d5c99ebc0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (SMG,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0x558d5c9ae3a0 "abc"\0 [UTF8 "abc"]
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 10
  MAGIC = 0x558d5c9af690
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_utf8
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_utf8(w)
    MG_LEN = -1
    MG_PTR = 0x558d5c99cb80
       0: 2 -> 2                     <-- Attached character offset
       1: 0 -> 0                     <-- Attached character offset
```

The difference in behaviour is due to different code being paths in the code being exercised based on the string format and what information is cached.

Comment: [Unicode::GCString](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::GCString) might be useful in cases where this is a problem. It depends on what answer you are trying to get.